# ahk script how to call itself without recursion?

Tags: autohotkey

my autohotkey script is always crashing for like every 3-5mins I don't know why there's no error message or why it is crashing? recursion probably? can anyone suggest me some idea how to go back to top
of main and continue the script without calling itself like recursion??
im kinda new to this language i hope you help me

heres my code

```
 home::
    main()
    {
    loot1() 
    }


    loot1()
    {
    ImageSearch,violetX, violetY, 266, 141, 579, 527, C:\image\loot.png
    If ErrorLevel
    mobs1() 
    else
    mousemove(%violetX%, %violetY%)
    MouseClick, left 
    main()
    }


    mobs1()
    {
    PixelSearch, X, Y, 22, 216, 776, 607, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
    If ErrorLevel
    mobs2()
    else
    mousemove(%X%, %Y%)
    MouseClick, left
    main()

    }


    mobs2()
    {
    ImageSearch,mobs2x, mobs2y, 243, 76, 776, 607, C:\image\green.png
    If ErrorLevel 
    tele() 
    else
    mousemove(%mobs2x%, %mobs2y%)
    MouseClick, left
    main()
     }

    tele()
    {
    ImageSearch,walkX, walkY, 394, 347, 413, 414, C:\image\walk.png
    If ErrorLevel
    tele2()
    else
    MouseClick, left, 200, 300
    main()


    }

    tele2()
    {
    Send {F9}
    sleep, 2000
    main()
    }
    return
```

EDIT 2 heres so far but its not returning to main loop

```
home::
Loop
    {
     loot1()        
    }
return




    loot1()
    {
    ImageSearch,violetX, violetY, 266, 141, 579, 527, C:\image\loot.png
    If ErrorLevel
    mobs1() 
    else
    mousemove(%violetX%, %violetY%)
    MouseClick, left 

    }


    mobs1()
    {
    PixelSearch, X, Y, 22, 216, 776, 607, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
    If ErrorLevel
    mobs2()
    else
    mousemove(%X%, %Y%)
    MouseClick, left


    }


    mobs2()
    {
    ImageSearch,mobs2x, mobs2y, 243, 76, 776, 607, C:\image\green.png
    If ErrorLevel 
    tele() 
    else
    mousemove(%mobs2x%, %mobs2y%)
    MouseClick, left

     }

    tele()
    {
    ImageSearch,walkX, walkY, 394, 347, 413, 414, C:\image\walk.png
    If ErrorLevel
    tele2()
    else
    MouseClick, left, 200, 300 ;-- walk



    }

    tele2()
    {
    Send {F9}
    sleep, 2000
    }
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling itself is pretty much what recursion means so I don't think "calling itself without recursion" is possible.

If you want to repeatedly call `loot1()` you need to remove your `main()` function and all calls to it from the other functions and replace it with:

```
home::
    Loop {
        loot1()
    }

    loot1() 
    {
    ; the rest of your code the same
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to work, it skips imagesearching. it just keeps teleporting.. how can i return to the main loop?   loot1()
    {
    ImageSearch,violetX, violetY, 266, 141, 579, 527, C:\image\loot.png
    If ErrorLevel
    mobs1() 
    else
    mousemove(%violetX%, %violetY%)
    MouseClick, left 
    main()    ;----- how to return to main loop?
    }

Comment: remove the call to main and it will execute `loot1()` again. @ArillleNahis

Comment: i removed the calling to main() but its not imagesearching..it keeps teleporting, please check my edit 2

Comment: @ArillleNahis What teleports where? Autohotkey can't teleport... how do you know it's not image searching?

Comment: tele2() is the only running  it skips loots(), mobs1() mobs2() any idea why?

Comment: @ArillleNahis Not possible, it's called from `mobs2()` which is called from `mobs1()` ... etc.